# Gmail Mail sender

Tags: java, email, gmail

I try to send an email by JAVA. The mail delivered to the inbox, however, instantly a new mail comes which says the following;

```
**Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
to-email@gmail.com

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain gmail.com by gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [2a00:1450:4010:c05::1b].

The error that the other server returned was:
550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
550 5.1.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596 tb1si15031715lbb.130 - gsmtp

**
```

how I can prevent this situation?

Comment: is this email adress is valid?

Comment: Oh no! thank you njjnex, I forget to update to-email@gmail.com part as the one that I want to send. Thank you very much for this question eheh:)